# Object.assign an concat - ES6 refactoring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

How can I refactor this redux reducer code with ES6? Concat I can replace with `...` right? But what about Object.assign?

```
import { FETCH_REQUEST, FETCH_SUCCESS, FETCH_FAILURE } from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  beersArray: [],
  errorMessage: '',
  skip: 0,
  limit: 0,
  hasMore: true,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        skip: action.skip,
        limit: action.limit,
        hasMore: true,
      });
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        beersArray: state.beersArray.concat(action.beers),
        hasMore: action.hasMore,
      });
    case FETCH_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        errorMessage: action.errorMessage,
        hasMore: false,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `Object.assign` with. Be aware that `...state` (spread properties) are proposal, so your environment need to support them.

```
return { ...state, isFetching: true, skip: action.skip, limit: action.limit, hasMore: true };
```

What about `concat`, you can write

```
{ beersArray: [...state.beersArray, ...action.beers] }
```

This will just destruct the items from the `state.beersArray` and `action.beers` , put them into the new array and assign to the `beersArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spread operator on `key-value` objects and `arrays` as well.

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_REQUEST:
      return {...state, { isFetching: true, skip: action.skip, limit: action.limit, hasMore: true}};
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, { isFetching: false, beersArray: [...state.beersArray, ...action.beers], hasMore: action.hasMore });
    case FETCH_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, { isFetching: false, errorMessage: action.errorMessage, hasMore: false });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

## Transitions

`state.beersArray.concat(action.beers)` to `[...state.beersArray, ...action.beers]`

`Object.assign({}, state, {other props}}` to `{ ...state, ...state, ...{other props} }`

---

#### [`Spread syntax (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

> [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.